# Highchart treemap color averages out

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using `Highchart treemap`, to show project build status. Pass in green & Fail in Red.

It works if there are some projects in pass state and some in fail.

But if all the projects are in pass state, highchart is showing them in brown (average of Green & Red). I guess that is because there is no fail project so it averages out the color.

Code:

```
Highcharts.chart(divId, {
            colorAxis: {
                minColor: '#00B300', // green
                maxColor: '#8fb200'  // red
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false,
                useHTML: true,
                labelFormatter: function () {
                    return this.name + ' (click to hide)';
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'treemap',
                layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
                data: mapData, // my JSON data containing projects status
            }],
            title: {
                text: 'Project Status',
                style: {
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            chart: {
                margin: [30, 0, 0, 0],
                height: 170
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled:false
            }

        });
```

Please suggest, what am I missing?

*Thank You*

Comment: If you make a JSfiddle where this can be seen and include your `mapData` object, or at least part of it, it will get you help a lot quicker.

Comment: @ewolden, I've uploaded it here. Please assist. Thanks. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rahulsaini/1k5by6pu/).

Comment: Could you also provide the data that works fine (pass & fail)?

Answer (score 1):

You could solve this by adding two fake points, one with `colorValue` minimum and one with `colorValue` maximium and turning off visibility for these two points. Assuming your colorValues go from 0 to 1 you can do this:

```
var mapData = [{
  "name": "project1",
  "value": 1,
  "colorValue": 1
}, {
  "name": "project2",
  "value": 1,
  "colorValue": 1
},{value: 1, colorValue: 0, visible: false}, {value: 1, colorValue: 1, visible: false}];
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/1k5by6pu/3/

Alternativley, you can add a fake series, with the same points:

```
 series: [{
   type: 'treemap',
   layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
   data: mapData,
 }, {
   type: 'treemap', 
   name: 'fakeSeries',
   visible: false, 
   data: [{value: 1, colorValue: 0}, {value: 1, colorValue: 1}]
 }]
```

**Working JSFiddle Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/0bse4x57/2/

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible, Beacuse we use max and min colour. Used other trick for that- Add 2 default value in mapData(1 for green and 1 for Red) and hide this block using j-query.
Can you give me json data here if you have not any problem ?

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/treemap-coloraxis